# Getting all data from multiple JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

What I am trying to do here is get all applicants who have either applied for a certain job or have been tagged for a certain job by picking a job and then selecting a tag to search by. Here is my sql statement that I am using.

```
SELECT ap.user_id, ap.job_id as jobId, date(app_date) AS appDate, count(*) AS `count`   ,jt.name AS title, a.*, ap.app_id
FROM applications ap
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON ap.job_id = j.job_id
LEFT JOIN job_titles jt ON jt.name = j.title
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON a.applicant_id = ap.user_id
LEFT JOIN applicant_tags at ON at.applicant_id = ap.user_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = at.tag_id
WHERE ap.favorite = 1
AND LOWER(jt.name) = LOWER('fisherman')
AND (LOWER(t.name) = LOWER('confident')
OR LOWER(t.name) = LOWER('hard worker'))
GROUP BY ap.app_id
HAVING `count` = '2'
ORDER BY jt.name
```

My problem here is that I am only getting applicants who have applied for that job and not those who have been tagged for that type of job. The job names themselves are not stored as tags but are instead linked to each applicant through the applicant_tags table which looks like this:

```
applicant_id | tag_id | job_id
34                0        4
34                4        0
34                0        5
32                7        0
```

The applicant_id links to applications through the applications user_id, tag_id by tags id, and job_id by the job_titles id. The tags table and job_titles table only have an id and name in them.

Here is the tags table:

```
id | tag_id
```

The job_titles table:

```
id | name
```

The applicants has all of the applicant's personal info(email, phone #) as well as the applicant_id which is being used as the foreign key.

Applications and jobs has too much info to list and only a few columns are actually being used.

The applications table

```
app_id | user_id | job_id | app_date | favorites .....
```

The jobs table

```
job_id | title | location | jobtype .....
```

The tag_id for an applicant is 0 if it has a job_id and vice versa. The tag names and job names are not stored as comma separated values but as a single value in one row which is linked to each applicant by their applicant_id. The job_id in jobs is the id of the job applied for, not the job name. Each applicant can have multiple tags associated with them and multiple job names associated with them. The tags statement LOWER(t.name) = LOWER(tag name) is added based on the number of tags being used in the search. I'm getting everything from applicants because that information and what's being called in applications is going to be displayed on the page.

applications ap is linked to jobs by ap.job_id, applicant_tags at by ap.applicant_id = at.applicant_id, and applicants by ap.applicant_id = a.applicant_id.

job_titles jt is linked to jobs j by jt.name = j.title and to applicant_tags at by j.id = at.job_id

tags t is linked to applicant_tags at by t.id = at.tag_id

I also cannot use aggregate tables.

So how can I get the applications that are linked to the job name not from jobs table to the job_titles table but from the applicant_tags table to the job_titles table?

-Edit

After refactoring my sql statement I can get it to where it shows all of the applicants but none of the tags and if I try to search for any of the tags, it returns no results.

```
SELECT ap.user_id, jt.id as jobId, date(app_date) AS appDate, jt.name AS title,   count(*) AS `count`, at.*, a.*, ap.app_id, t.*    
FROM applications ap                                 
INNER JOIN applicants a ON ap.user_id = a.applicant_id
LEFT JOIN applicant_tags at ON at.applicant_id = a.applicant_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON at.tag_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN job_titles jt ON at.job_id = jt.id
WHERE ap.favorite = '1'
AND LOWER(jt.name) = LOWER('fisherman')
GROUP BY ap.app_id
HAVING `count` = '1'
ORDER BY jt.name
```

Comment: What's up with group by? I don't even see that being called in the Query. By standard aren't you supposed to group by on all items before aggregrate function? (Count (*)) I know this isn't right in all cases, but I would check that first

Comment: Just added the missing HAVING clause and the group by is used to get rid of duplicate applications.

Comment: that's not going to get rid of duplicates it's just going to return the record if there is 2 of them, they could still be the same.

Comment: You are actually trying to run 2 different queries. This is best done with `UNION` or `UNION ALL`: `SELECT applicant_id, 0 AS tag_id, job_id FROM ...query about applied job... UNION ALL SELECT applicant_id, tag_id, 0 AS job_id FROM ...query about tagged...`. Unfortunately you have too little information about your tables relations for me to give you a full query.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at nested queries, on another note....this can be found below...
http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/sql/sql_nested_queries.html

As for this query, it would be easier if you wrapped up all the applicant information into a single aggregate table. Then join the job id stuff into another table, or use original, add indexes appropriately so it doesnt time out, and boom...much easier.

```
SELECT ap.user_id, ap.job_id as jobId, date(app_date) AS appDate, count(*) AS `count` ,jt.name AS title, `a.*` -- a.* is this necessary? It would help if you were explicit
FROM applications ap
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON ap.job_id = j.job_id --take all items from applications and puta  jobid to them
LEFT JOIN job_titles jt ON jt.name = j.title -- now you are trying to add a title to job from ANOTHER table while retaining all records from applications
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON a.applicant_id = ap.user_id --then you want the applicant that matches the criteria to each application record
LEFT JOIN applicant_tags at ON at.applicant_id = ap.user_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = at.tag_id
WHERE ap.favorite = 1
AND LOWER(jt.name) = LOWER('fisherman')
AND (LOWER(t.name) = LOWER('confident')
OR LOWER(t.name) = LOWER('hard worker')) 
GROUP BY ap.app_id -- how are you grouping by something that is not being called?
HAVING `count` = '2' -- They need to have two records, does not matter if they are the same
ORDER BY jt.name -- This is fine
```

Okay aside from my comments this is actually legit. I would however create an aggregrate table of the Applicant information, and then do a single join, on that table to make things much easier

Looks like the tables you are using are:

Applications
join
Applicants  on criteria

inner join these tables

Applicants_tags join with tags into sample_tags
tags
jobs -- join this with 
job_titles for jobs table

Comment: I cannot create an aggregate table of the two unfortunately. I also need everything from applicants because that is the bulk of what's being displayed on the page.

Comment: you should include that in your question...why can't you use aggregates?

Comment: Doing that would require me to redo pretty much every page on the entire website and I'm not allowed to modify any of the data in either table.

Comment: so what DB are you using ? Aggregrates are beautiful because they don't have to relate back to anything...if you want to start a chat, we can...

Comment: InnoDB for applications and MyISAM for everything else. This website has gone through many different people so everything is very inconsistent.

Comment: And sure, we can start a chat.

Comment: It won't let me start a chat. I think I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. I had to use a subquery with an IN clause:

```
SELECT ap.user_id, jt.id as jobId, date(app_date) AS appDate, jt.name AS title, count(*) AS `count`, at.*, a.*,ap.app_id
FROM applications ap
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON ap.job_id = j.job_id
LEFT JOIN job_titles jt ON jt.name = j.title
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON a.applicant_id = ap.user_id
LEFT JOIN applicant_tags at ON at.applicant_id = ap.user_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = at.tag_id
WHERE ap.favorite = 1
AND (
    LOWER(jt.name) = LOWER('fisherman') OR 'fisherman' IN(SELECT jt.name FROM applicant_tags at 
    LEFT JOIN job_titles jt ON at.job_id = jt.id 
    WHERE at.applicant_id = a.applicant_id))
AND (LOWER(t.name) = LOWER('confident')
    OR LOWER(t.name) = LOWER('hard worker'))
GROUP BY ap.app_id
HAVING `count` = '2'
ORDER BY jt.name
```

Thank you all for your help though!